# Why when I enter 1999-10-17 it submits 1999-10-01 React native?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to submit a form with a birthdate. But for one or another reason when I for example enter 1999-10-17 it submits 1999-10-01. It just always removes the last number and puts a 0 before. I've been trying everything I could imagine but nothing works...
Why this happens and how can I solve it???

```
  const [birthdate, setBirthdate] = useState('');
  const [yearB, setYearB] = useState('');
  const [monthB, setMonthB] = useState('');
  const [dayB, setDayB] = useState('');
  const updateBirthdate = () => {
    setBirthdate(`${yearB}-${monthB}-${dayB}`);
  };
  const handleYearBChange = (yearB) => {
    setYearB(yearB);
    updateBirthdate();
  };

  const handleMonthBChange = (monthB) => {
    setMonthB(monthB);
    updateBirthdate();
  };

  const handleDayBChange = (dayB) => {
    setDayB(dayB);
    updateBirthdate();
  };
     <TextInput
        value={yearB}
        onChangeText={handleYearBChange}
        onSubmitEditing={() => yearBInput.current.blur()}
        placeholder="year"
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />
      <TextInput
        value={monthB}
        onChangeText={handleMonthBChange}
        onSubmitEditing={() => monthBInput.current.blur()}
        placeholder="month"
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />
      <TextInput
        value={dayB}
        onChangeText={handleDayBChange}
        onSubmitEditing={() => dayBInput.current.blur()}
        placeholder="day"
        keyboardType="numeric"
      />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use useEffect hook to update the birthdate with each rendering, follow the example:

```
  const updateBirthdate = useCallback(() => {
    setBirthdate(`${yearB}-${monthB}-${dayB}`);
  }, [yearB, monthB, dayB]);

  const handleYearBChange = (yearB) => {
    setYearB(yearB);
  };

  const handleMonthBChange = (monthB) => {
    setMonthB(monthB);
  };

  const handleDayBChange = (dayB) => {
    setDayB(dayB);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    updateBirthdate()
  }, [updateBirthdate])
```

Comment: Here is a bit more explanation to the solution. The reason the original code does not work is that after `setYearB()` is called, react native goes on to execute `updateBirthdate()` immediately, without waiting for `yearB` to be actually updated. Hence, it is not guaranteed that each `updateBirthdate()` call has access to the most updated states. The solution works because `useEffect` is triggered only AFTER `yearB`, `monthB`, or `dayB` has been modified. Thus, the function call inside `useEffect` always has access to the most updated states.